# Bash script to show updating information in terminal

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that displays the output from a python script. I want the output refreshed every second, so my script looks like this (`run.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

export INTERVAL=1
export SCRIPT="something.py"

while [ true ]
    do
    clear
    python ${SCRIPT}
    sleep ${INTERVAL}
    done
```

The screen, however, flickers while the python script works (there's some web access involved). How can I make this more sophisticated and wait for the script to finish before clearing what I used to have?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use watch. It will only update the screen when the entire script is done, and it'll take care of things like clearing the screen, and dealing with output that is larger than a single screen.

`watch -n ${INTERVAL} 'python ${SCRIPT}'`

If you want to see an example of how watch works with long-running tasks, do this:

`watch 'date; echo; echo Long running task...; sleep 3; echo; date'`

Answer (score 0):

A quick way is to establish a temporary file:

```
tmpf=`mktemp`

while [ condition ]
  do
  python ${SCRIPT} > $tmpf
  clear
  cat $tmpf
  sleep ${INTERVAL}
  done

rm $tmpf
```

This requires you to do some cleanup on exit, though. Other than that I would suggest moving the whole loop into python because really, why not? You can use subprocess to fork out another shell and even get a more generic program.

**Supplement:**
You can make do with the *trap* builtin ([here](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0160.php)'s an article on it) to do the cleanup automatically when you kill your script.

Answer (score 0):

It's an ugly hack but doesn't use temporary files or fifo's:

```
a=$(clear; python ${SCRIPT})
echo $a
```

but seriously: the best way is to incorporate the screen clearing in your script. Give it a switch `-clear` or something like it.